# How to set the installed(who is installing the RPM) user and group privileges while packing the RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, rhel, packing

> I am just wondering if there is a way to specify the current user(who
>   is installing the RPM) user:group privileges to installed folder of
>   RPM(/usr/lib/appfloder) in the Spec(.spec) file.

Example: Currently while installing the RPM it is considering root:root privileges if we do not create the user and group and not added in section 
(%defattr(777, maya, maya, 777)) in the spec file. if we add defattr it is considering maya as a user.

> Expecting, please consider the current user 'user1' is installing the
>   RPM, the privileges should under 'user1'. if 'user2' is installing the
>   RPM it should under 'user2'..    Why?
>
> I have an RPM package which install on /usr/lib/app and run as a
>   service. And my application needs the current user home directory to
>   search for some package which is installed for the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user who installs the `rpm` is always **root**, because you need **root** privileges to be able to install an rpm.

So you cannot do this. You need to find some other way, a package should not provide files inside the `/home` directory of a user. If you have general config to package; put it in `/etc`.